# How to make the screen transparent?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

i am trying to add a spinner to my app when show() is clicked the current page should move on to transparent view, and only my spinner should be highlighted

```
<button (click)="show()">show</button>
<button (click)="hide()">hide</button>
<div class="container" *ngIf="isBusy">
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <ion-spinner name="bubbles" color="primary"></ion-spinner>
</div>
```

currently i could able to show and hide spinner, what i need is when spinner is shown all content in my view should move to transparent mode and only spinner should be displayed not the other contents

Comment: you mean the backdrop div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have your content inside some wrapper div. Then in the Busy state you need to add to this div some class which turns off pointer events and sets lower opacity

```
<div [class.nonclickable]="isBusy">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<div class="container" *ngIf="isBusy">
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <ion-spinner name="bubbles" color="primary"></ion-spinner>
</div>
```

And styling:

```
.nonclickable {
    opacity: .3;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<div *ngIf="!isBusy">
    //content
</div>
<div class="container" *ngIf="isBusy">
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
    <ion-spinner name="bubbles" color="primary"></ion-spinner>
</div>
```

Comment: if i do like this content will gets hidden i want contest to be present it should be in disabled state

Comment: What do you mean by 'in a disabled state' ?